# Android progress bar

Tags: android, android-widget

HI All,

I m calling one webservice(SOAP) on Click of button. Web service is taking around 20 secs to get response. in the mean time i want to show progress bar.

So how can i do that?
where should i code for progress bar? on button click? any source code, example would be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is to use an AsyncTask and use a ProgressBar along with it. Here is a sample which I found by googling http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html. Just use progressBar.setIndeterminate(true) to get a spinning progressbar rather than the one going from 0 to 100%

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask