# Updating progress dialog in Activity from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my app I am doing some intense work in `AsyncTask` as suggested by Android tutorials and showing a `ProgressDialog` in my main my activity:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "title", "text");
new MyTask().execute(request);
```

where then later in `MyTask` I post results back to activity:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Request, Void, Result> {

    @Override protected Result doInBackground(Request... params) {
        // do some intense work here and return result
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Result res) {
        postResult(res);
    }
}
```

and on result posting, in main activity I hide the dialog:

```
protected void postResult( Result res ) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    // do something more here with result...
}
```

So everything is working fine here, but I would like to somehow to update the progress dialog to able to show the user some real progress instead just of dummy "Please wait..." message. Can I somehow access the progress dialog from `MyTask.doInBackground`, where all work is done?

As I understand it is running as separate Thread, so I cannot "talk" to main activity from there and that is why I use `onPostExecute` to push the result back to it. But the problem is that `onPostExecute` is called only when all work is already done and I would like to update progress the dialog in the middle of doing something.

Any tips how to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

AsyncTask has method `onProgressUpdate(Integer...)` that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during `doInBackground()` by calling `publishProgress()`.

Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

you can update from AsyncTask's method `onProgressUpdate(YOUR_PROGRESS)` that can be invoked from `doInBackground` method by calling `publishProgress(YOUR_PROGRESS)`
the data type of YOUR_PROGRESS can be defined from `AsyncTask<Int, YOUR_PROGRESS_DATA_TYPE, Long>`