# async task sending result to gui

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can an async task send **periodically** a result to the GUI?

For example: I have 3 things I'd like my async task to do. After each thing, I'd like
to send a string back to the gui: `"task x completed"`

Can I do this without creating 3 async tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out the method onProgressUpdate() and publishProgress().

Here's an example i found very quickly, which may or may not work. But I think you have enough information to figure it out for yourself.

[Updating progress dialog in Activity from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask)

Comment: If you like my answer please remember to choose it as an accepted answer! Not only will it help me out, but people will see that you accept a lot of questions, and be more willing to help you out.

Comment: first I try things out before selecting the best answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `onProgressUpdate()` to generate display in the UI .

```
boolean first = false, second = false, third = false; // task not completed yet


doInBackground()
{
// complete your task and set the corresponding boolean to **true**
}

onProgressUpdate(..)
{
if(first== true) Toast.makeText(context, "Task 1 finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//similarly check which task has been done
}
```

***EDIT :*** You can also check out another method called `publishProgress()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other suggestions: if you have access to activity from your asycntask, then you may also use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`. Yet another option - if you have access to any view added on the screen, then you can also use it for safe UI updates via `View.post(Runnable action)`. These are safe to call from `doInBackground()`.