# How to get progress dialog until get the response from service in android?

Tags: android, service, xmpp, progressdialog, asmack

I am using service for running long background tasks in my application, in the service these functions are running login to XMPP and getting some data from XMPP server. i want to show the progress bar upto login completed. How to get response from service to activity to Update progress bar properly to avoid some exceptions in UI. 
I am calling service like this

```
final Intent gtalk_intent = new Intent(AccountsActivity.this, GtalkService.class);             
gtalk_intent.putExtra("user_name", acc.getAcc_Name());
gtalk_intent.putExtra("user_pass", acc.getAcc_Pass());               
startService(gtalk_intent);
```

this is the code from service

```
public class PmService extends Service {

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {               
      return mBinder;
   }

   public class PmBinder extends Binder {
      public PmService getService() {
         return PmService.this;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

      super.onCreate(); 
      context = this;       
      app_preferences = new AppPreferences(this);

      chat_source = new ChatsDataSource(this);  
      chat_source.open();
   } 

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();       
      if(extras == null)  {         
         full_name = extras.getString("user_name");
         if(full_name.contains("@")) {
            String[] _na = full_name.split("@");
            U_name = _na[0];
        }
        U_pass = extras.getString("user_pass");                    
    }       
    new PmAsync().execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class PmAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {          
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {          
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server_host, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
        configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
        m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try {            
            m_connection.connect();                  
            Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);              
        } catch (XMPPException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        try {               
            m_connection.login(U_name, U_pass);
            setPacketFilters();                     
        } catch (XMPPException e) {                 
        }

        return null;
    }       
}
```

i want to show the progress bar upto login completed, how to response from service after login completed?

Comment: Call methods of your `Binder`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev How?, can you provide any example code related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Via `Binder` you can send callbacks to your `Activity`, which means that you can update UI.

1. Add according method to your `Binder` (let's name it `onProgress`)
2. From your `AsyncTask` call method of this `Binder`
3. In order to know about progress updates consider using Observer pattern (in other words - your `Activity` should listen for updates of your `Binder`, or more specifically - of calling `Binder.onProgress` method)

Comment: I am not getting how to start this, can you post any tutorials on this.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy sorry, I gave you enough information - you can do this by your own. This link will be useful for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score -1):

You can update the progress bar via overriding the onProgress() method 
here is a close to your case that you can refer to.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask)

Comment: onProgressUpdate() is the one that you have to override, 
this method is in the AsynckTask

Comment: I am not talking about the showing the progress in asynctask, it's related to service. look at the Question clearly.