# making the app unresponsive for a minute

Tags: android, android-intent

I need help on how to make the app unresponsive for a minute. I have two classes,the first class start another activity for results while the second class  respond to the intent request.what I want is for the second class not to give the results if the request is made within one mintute.I have no control of the first class because the request  is coming from ODK(openDataKit). I have tried  using the following code in the my-second class:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("value","user_id" );
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

            finish();

               try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

Comment: You realize if an app is unresponsive for more than a few seconds the system will force stop it right?

Comment: I'd kill any app that doesn't respond in 5 seconds, let alone 1 minute, if the system doesn't do that for me.

Comment: Bad idea to make is unresponsive, use progress dialog if you have to block. One minute seems too long though, try alternative designs (ex: disabling buttons till init is done...etc).

Answer (score 0):

you can create an asyncTask for the second class. do the sleep inside doInBackground(), and return the results in the onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem would indeed be using an AsyncTask, and showing a ProgressDialog while that is happening.

For a concise example, look at the most popular answer it his question: [progressDialog in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask).

Other than that, making the user wait for a minute is a VERY bad idea. Usually my attention span lasts for only 30s max, if something is loading. If you do need to load stuff, maybe you should try to use `onProgressUpdate()` to do some content changing. See this question for more details: [Updating progress dialog in Activity from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask)