# How to use Async task with progressbar from a different activity in android

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, download

I've used elasticView progressbar library in this project. When I use this directly in a single `Activity` with an `AsyncTask` it works fine, but when I create the new java class for downloading and accessed from the `MainActivity`. It shows class not found exception. Here is my complete code with error log.

---

MainActivity

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                download d=new download();
                d.startdownload();
            }
        });
    }
```

---

download.java

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import it.michelelacorte.elasticprogressbar.ElasticDownloadView;

public class download extends AppCompatActivity {
    ElasticDownloadView mElasticDownloadView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.elastic);

        mElasticDownloadView = (ElasticDownloadView) findViewById(R.id.elastic_download_view);
        mElasticDownloadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        startdownload();
    }

    public void startdownload() {

        final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(download.this);
        mElasticDownloadView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        downloadTask.execute("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg");
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;

        public DownloadTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {


            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;

                    if (fileLength > 0) {
                        int status = ((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                        publishProgress(status);
                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mElasticDownloadView.startIntro();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            mElasticDownloadView.setProgress(10);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mElasticDownloadView.success();
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

---

activity_main.xml

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="net.logicalsteps.download_notif.MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/elastic"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="start download"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

elastic.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <it.michelelacorte.elasticprogressbar.ElasticDownloadView
        android:id="@+id/elastic_download_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

---

error log:

---

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: net.logicalsteps.download_notif, PID: 23132  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.michelelacorte.elasticprogressbar.ElasticDownloadView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object referenc
        at net.logicalsteps.download_notif.download.startdownload(download.java:41)
        at net.logicalsteps.download_notif.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5162)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20873)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: First start the activity download so the views can be initialized then play with the visibility of views. or don't use the another activity download just make AsynTask extended class and change the views in mainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cause of error

The reason this is happening is because when the system starts the `download` activity, it executes `download.onCreate` which sets `mElasticDownloadView = ...`. But when you create it in `onClick` you do not call `onCreate` so `mElasticDownloadView` is not initialized.

#### Using Activities

Now in `onClick` you create an instance of the `download` Activity:

```
download d=new download();
d.startdownload();
```

This is not the usual way to create activities. If you do it this way, the activity will not have all of its UI inflated from the layout XML file and so there is no progress bar either. If you want to show the activity, you should instead use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, download.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, if you want to pass a message to the Activity, you could pass it through the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

Then in `download.onStart` you can retrieve this message `getIntent().getStringExtra(...)`.

However, in your `download.onCreate` you call `startdownload` anyway, so you shouldn't need to do the message passing.

Learn more about this here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: :Thanks for your valuable information.i understood the mistake.

Comment: can you sujjest me a way to handle this without using intent.i mean,i need this progressbar in the screen untill the download finishes like a floating item.it should not be gone even if we move out to another page.

Comment: You could compose a single Activity from a number of Views (one of them would be the progress bar). If not, you should take a look at Fragments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start an `Activity` from another with an `Intent`, else, your class will be initialized, but the `Activity` will not start its Lifecycle (the `onCreate` method and such will not be called):

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), download.class);
            startActivity(downloadIntent);
        }
    });
```

If you don't want to open a new `Activity`, you could move your `AsyncTask` to your `MainActivity`, and while the it downloads, you could show an custom `AlertDialog` with your `ProgressBar`. You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask).

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have to look at here

```
 download d=new download();
 d.startdownload();
```

You called `startdownload()` method but till that time `onCreate` of `download` Activity isn't called so that `mElasticDownloadView` could not be initialized. So that initialize that inside either `startdownload` method too, or anywhere you feel comfortable, OR start the Activity `download` in `onClick()` method.