# Populate TextView on main activity form another class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem updating a `TextView` on my `MainActivity` form a class which is `Async` I have seen that I need to set the `Context` of the second class to that of the `MainActivity` but I don't know how to achieve this in this scenario.  My app looks like this.

```
 class RestOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) { 
    //Java.net Http    transaction happens here 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //I wish to set the value of the TextView with the result here!
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask

Comment: Sorry! I need to get the value returned in the OnPostExecute and populate a TextView in my MAinActivity with the value (result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in another class, you should get a reference to `MainActivity` through the constructor (note that I use `WeakReference` here so that when the activity is destroyed the `onPostExecute` won't be executed (because it does not need to) and the AsyncTask won't leak memory)

```
//first you have to change the param (the last one) to String so your doInBackground would return String
class RestOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {
private WeakReference<MainActivity> weakRef;

public RestOperation(MainActivity activity) {
    weakRef = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
//Java.net Http transaction happens here 
//You need to return some value here to set to the text view later
return "Something";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    MainActivity activity = weakRef.get();
    if (activity != null) {
        //activity is still alive, updates the text view
        activity.updateText(result);
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity:

```
new RestOperation(this).execute("Your input param");
```

also make another method in MainActivity:

```
public void updateText(String result) {
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Everthing compiles apart form 'new RestOperation(this).execute("Your input param"); this is underlined in red and I get : RestOperation  (mainActivity) in RestOperation cannot be applied.

Comment: Ah found the correct way to call the operation;

new RestOperation(MainActivity.this).execute("Your input param");

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

**#1** : Make a constructor for your `RestOperation` class to get the `Context` from your `Activity` like this :

```
    public RestOperation(MainActivity activityContext){
        this._activityContext = activityContext;
    }
```

**#2** : Pass the `Activity` context while initializing the `AsyncTask` class like this :

```
new RestOperation(MainActivity.this).execute("yours","params","here");
```

So, your `AsyncTask` class should look like this :

```
class RestOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {
    MainActivity _activityContext;
    public RestOperation(MainActivity activityContext){
        this._activityContext = activityContext;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
        //Java.net Http    transaction happens here 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ((TextView)_activityContext.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).setText(yourText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It'll be good if you will create interface which will be call at onPostExecute and at Main activity implement that interface and get your value and set value with textview.
>
> 2.newrestOperation(YourActivity.this,textviewobject).execute("yours","params","here");

So, your AsyncTask class should look like this :

```
Textview mtxt;
class RestOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  {
    Context _activityContext;
    public RestOperation(Context activityContext,Textview txt){
        this._activityContext = activityContext;
         this.mtxt = txt;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
        //Java.net Http    transaction happens here 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {enter code here
        mtxt .setText(yourText);
    }
}
```

But #1 is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: I am new to Android so please bear with me! RestOperation is a separate class so textview is not available in OnPostExecute. If I attempt to add a reference to the TextView I get cannot resolve findViewById!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
class RestOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  {

Context context; 
add public RestOperation (Contex cntx) {
this.context = cntx;
}
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) { //Java.net Http    transaction happens here }

@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //I wish to set the value of the TextView with the result here!
    }
```

And when you cat this task

```
new ResrOperation(getApplicationContext()).excute();
```

Then you can access to items from main activity

**Another choise**

You can Overide onPostExecute method in your main activiry and then you will have acces to activity elemets too (In this case no context nedded)

```
new ResrOperation(){
@Overide 
void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     // access elemets from activity
 }
}.excute();
```

Answer (score 0):

First write an `interface` in the `Async` class

```
CompleteListener completeListener;

public void setListener(CompleteListener cmpltListnr) {
   this.completeListener = cmpltListnr;
}

public interface CompleteListener {
    void OnCompleteListener(String result);
}
```

and `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if ( completeListener != null ) {
        completeListener.OnCompleteListener(""+result);
    }
}
```

and `implement` the listener in the `Activity` you want. and override the function
and assign `this` to the interface by

```
 yourAsynClassObject.setListener(this);

 @Override
 public void OnCompleteListener(String result) {
    textview.setText("" + result);
 }
```

Comment: Not quite sure how you set up your listener from my main activity RestOperation.setListener(this);  I get  'cannot be referenced from a static context!

Comment: @joebohen Create object of `RestOperation` and then call `setListener()`