# AsyncTask with a ProgressDialog and Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am attempting to use `AsyncTask` to load a file of determinate length. My `AsyncTask` looks something like this:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, null, "Loading", false);
}


protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    if (values.length == 2) {
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        dialog.setMax(values[1]);
    }
}
```

in my `doInBackground()` implementation I call `publishProgress(bytesSoFar, maxBytes);` inside my loading loop and in the `onPostExecute()` I call `dialog.dismiss()`.

However, I can't get the `ProgressDialog` to show anything but an indeterminate spinner. I want to see a horizontal progress bar that shows the progress as the loading happens. I've debugged and can see that `onProgressUpdate()` gets called with sane values and that the dialog's methods are getting called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progressbar togther with asyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add Style to your progress dialog with before you show it `.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: It looks like I was calling setStyle() before rather than setProgressStyle(). Also, I was under the impression that the ProgressDialog.show() method with a boolean indeterminate flag would do that work for you (otherwise what's the point?). Guess I was wrong!

Answer (score 9):

Use this code in your `onPreExecute()`.

```
 ProgressDialog prog;
 prog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
 prog.setTitle(title);
 prog.setMessage(msg);       
 prog.setIndeterminate(false);
 prog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
 prog.show();
```