# How to use AsyncTask to display ProgressBar and load Rss

Tags: android, rss, progress-bar, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask to display a progressBar while loading Rss News. Because this is my first time i m using asyncTask i dont know if my method is right,so could you please tell me if it looks good to you?Its working but i want just to be sute!Thanks

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask_nea extends
       AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          private ProgressDialog dialog;
        int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayRss();
             dialog.dismiss();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              dialog = ProgressDialog.show(nea.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            myProgress = 0;
        }

        @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadFeed();
            return null;
        }



    }
```

**loadFeed();**

```
private void loadFeed(){
        try{ 
            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();

            }
        catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("OSFP.News",t.getMessage(),t);


            finish();
        }
    }
```

**displayRss();**

```
private void displayRss(){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> List_nea = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(messages.size());


        for (Message msg : messages){

            des.add(msg.getDescription());// keimeno
            text.add(msg.getTitle());// titlos
            url.add(msg.getLink());// link
            imgl.add(msg.getImgLink());

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", msg.getTitle());
        map.put("date", msg.getDate());     


        List_nea.add(map);
        ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, List_nea, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"name", "date"}, new int[] {R.id.TextView01, R.id.TextView02});
        this.setListAdapter(mSchedule);
        }

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(400);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );

    animation.setDuration(400);
    set.addAnimation(animation);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
    ListView listViewn = getListView();        
    listViewn.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progressbar togther with asyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update the progress bar you need to be making calls to the [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) function. You're not doing that anywhere in your code. If I were you I'd pass a reference of the AsyncTask down into your loadFeed function. Something like this:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadFeed(this);
        return null;
    }

private void loadFeed(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask){
        // make calls to publishProgress in here.
           try{ 
            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();

            }
        catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("OSFP.News",t.getMessage(),t);


            finish();
        }
    }
```

You'll also need to implement the `onProgressUpdate()` method which you have not. This is where you'll actually update the value of your progress bar.

```
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
     }
```

Comment: Updated my answer. As to the to the app crashing when there's not internet connection and using a toast in loadfeed, those are different questions. Ask new questions for them. Before you do that though, try doing some research first (i.e. google about it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
This is the correct workflow, showing the progress dialog before execution on the UI thread (could have been done outside this class too, but this way seems better), doing your work on the doInBackground method, updating your ProgressDialog using publishProgress() if needed, then dismissing your ProgressDialog and showing the results onPostExecute(), in your UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loadFeed parser you can use a reference of the AsyncTask with the method `publishProgress` to send progress updates to the `onProgressUpdate` where you can update the progress bar.