# How to get progressBar in AsyncTask onProgressUpdate Method in android

Tags: android

I am developing a base adapter in `getView()` method I am calling to `AsyncTask` and in `ASyncTask` `onProgressUpdate()` method, I want to get the `ProgressBar` to update my `progressBar` but How? Because `onProgressUpdate()` I cannot pass the `ProgressBar` as a parameter. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progressbar togther with asyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask)

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is wrong, you should not call the AsyncTask in the getView, you should call it once and then using the results in your adapter. While executing your asynctask you can update the progress bar through the method publishProgress.

Here an [example](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/06/basic-asynctask-with-progress-bar.html) which shows how to update a progress bar while executing an AsyncTask

Comment: link out of date

Answer (score 0):

Calling Asyntask from getView() will considerably slow down your listview performance and may lead your app to crash. Updating the progress bar in UI thread can be done using publishProgress() from do in background.