# Android AsyncTask Progress bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Progressbar togther with asyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask)

I am having a expandableListView in a project . If somebody clicks on the group then data must be load and loading time a progress bar must come.I want to do it by Async Task .please give me example code for that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please try this

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //declare other objects as per your need
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {   

         //do loading operation here  
        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
 }
```

You can call this using

```
LoadData task = new LoadData();
task.execute();
```

Comment: He wants along with Loading time.. Oops...!

Comment: how can we get in our called method that the task has finished??

Comment: The task to be done after finishing Async Task can be placed in `onPostExecute`

Comment: How to make other thadreds wait until the value from Asnyc task comes??

Comment: @abhishekameta, there's a `get()` method for that. In this example it will look like this: `task.get()`

Comment: @Sandy how to use runOnUiThread() method in doInBackGround()

Comment: @PratikButani Pass instance of your activity to asyncTask class and override runOnUiThread() like  this. instanceOfYourActivity.runOnUiThread() in your doInBackGround();

Comment: @Sandy but progressbar is displaying late