# How to add progress bar to standalone Asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an asynctask that is in its own activity.  I pass it a string value and it connects to my web service and downloads Json data based on the name I pass in, returning the Json resultset.  Works great.

I'd like to add a progress spinner to the asynctask, but I'm stymied as to how to do it.  I've perused this and many other blogs, and come close but have not yet found the solution.  It seems I either need to have the asynctask in with an Activity class to get the context or I have to pass in the context as a parameter -- but I need the input parameter to be String.  I've read about the possibility of building an Object that could hold the String and a Context parameter, but I'm very new to Java and don't know how to build something like that nor have I found a good explanation of how to do so.  So often an explanation gets right up to what I need and then says, "... and then you do X and that's it," when X is what I need to know.

All I want is just a spinner thingie to whirl while the download happens.  No text, no dialog, just a spinner.

Comment: would you mind to share the code that u have tried ?

Comment: I don't have it handy right now.  I'll post it this evening.

Comment: Here's my code.  This is an activity all by itself.

Apparently not.  I posted my code and was told I was -419 characters to go.  What do I have to do to get it all in?  It's not all that long.

Comment: I think we've misunderstood your question. A ProgressBar is an Android View Widget which HAS to be added to an Activity/Fragment, which are the only components in Android which handle View components. If you want to show a ProgressBar in an AsyncTask, you have to place it in an Activity and pass a reference to the activity/progressbar to the asynctask.

Comment: I've come to that conclusion as well.  I'm working now with the various ideas presented here and elsewhere in the blog to see what I can make work.  I'll post again when I've reached the end of my trek.

Comment: Here is more simple way check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar) out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ProgressBar(this is what it's actually called, Spinners are like drop down menus in Android) to the layout of the Activity where you're initializing your AsyncTask.

Then make two functions `startProgress()` and `stopProgress()`, which start and stop the progress bar.

Give your AsyncTask a reference to the Activity, either by sending it during initialization or execution, or making a function in your asyncTask `setActivity(MyActivity activity)` and call it between your AsyncTask initialization and execution.

Override the `onPreExecute()` of your AsyncTask to call `activity.startProgress()` and `onPostExecute()` to call `activity.stopProgress()`.

EDIT: You can also try passing a reference to the ProgressBar in the constructor of your AsyncTask. Get the reference to the ProgressBar in the `onCreate()` method of your activity, then add it in the AsyncTask constructor. In the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods of the AsyncTask, start and stop the progress bars accordingly.

Comment: Given the standalone nature of my AsyncTask as explained above, will setActivity work in a separate thread, and indeed, class?  My whole conundrum is getting context to it, which is lacking without an Activity class (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Vinay, you reached to the heart of the problem by realizing that I shouldn't be running an AsyncTask as a standalone.  I modified my code to put an Activity class in with the AsyncTask, and passed that context.

Being so new to Java, I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology yet regarding activities, classes, etc., but this is what worked and has taught me to use the AsyncTask only with an Activity.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Request, Void, Result> {

 protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();               
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "", true, false);
        }

    @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Request... params) {
        // do some work here 
            return true;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Result res) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to have the problem of getting context into the AsyncTask, at least as far as Eclipse tells me.  Mine is truly standalone and not part of another Activity class, i.e. there is no "onCreate" in it.  Therefore, the command "this" is invalid in my case.  My entire class starts with "extends AsyncTask" and ends with it -- nothing else is included.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass various parameters to an `AsyncTask`, not just one!

One way to do this is to make member variables in your AsyncTask and initialize them using a constructor that accepts parameters.
For example:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<null, null, null> {
String mFirstParam = null;
Context mContext = null;
// Constructor which accepts parameters
public MyAsyncTask(String _firstParam, Context _context){
 this.mFirstParam = _firstParam;
 this.mContext = _context;
 }
}
```

When you create an instance of your `AsyncTask`, create it as follows:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(myFirstStringParam, mySecondContextParam);
task.execute();
```

Now you can use both these parameters throughout the scope of your `AsyncTask`.

Consider passing the `ImageView` containing of "loading" image and set its Visibility to `View.GONE` once you have finished downloading your data.

i.e. download your data in the `doInBackground` method and then change the ImageViews visibility to `View.GONE` in the `onPostExecute` method

Comment: This solution is intriguing.  I'll give it a whirl this evening and see what I can make happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the progress bar instance to AsyncTask when your create it in its constructor. Here is a downloader example by using AsyncTask -

```
public void downloadFile(String url, String path, ProgressDialog progress) {

    DownloadFileAsync downloader = new DownloadFileAsync(progress);

    File file = new File(path);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    downloader.execute(url, path);
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private final WeakReference<ProgressDialog> progressbarReference;

    public DownloadFileAsync(ProgressDialog progress) {
        progressbarReference = new WeakReference<ProgressDialog>(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            /*
             * android.util.Log.v("downloadFile", "Lenght of file: " +
             * lenghtOfFile + ":" + aurl[1]);
             */
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(aurl[1]);

            try {
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""
                            + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

            } finally {

                if (output != null) {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }

                if (input != null) {

                    input.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            ProgressDialog p = null;

            if (progressbarReference != null) {
                p = progressbarReference.get();
            }

            if (p != null && p.isShowing()) {
                p.dismiss();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        if (progressbarReference != null) {
            ProgressDialog p = progressbarReference.get();

            if (p != null) {
                p.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

        ProgressDialog p = null;

        if (progressbarReference != null) {
            p = progressbarReference.get();
        }

        if (p != null && p.isShowing()) {
            p.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

ProgressDialog is a custom Dialog which have a progress bar inside it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This solution seems to have possibilities, but my need is to return a resultset from the AsyncTask to the main thread.  Right now I can do that with the "new GetData.execute(string).get();" command.  If I partner the AsyncTask in an activity as above, what would the call be back in my main thread?  I have yet to figure out all the calling techniques in Java to return data (I'm self-educating).

Comment: I don't know what you did on your AsyncTask class, but I think you can modify your AsyncTask a little, just modify your class constructor and add some variable members in it, so you can pass progress bar to your AsyncTask, and in the class, you can do what you want to do. For instance, first you set up a progress spinner (maybe use a dialog), and then in AsyncTask <onPostExecute> your can close dialog <it's complete>. You don't need to copy all codes I sent here.