# ProgressBar and whole application freezes

Tags: android, android-progressbar, ui-thread

I have an application and it freezes when I show a `ProgressBar` on the screen. When I increase the size of a `ProgressBar` or when I use a `View` instead of `ProgressBar` it doesn't freeze.

When it freezes LogCat logs:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer(13909): GL Error after OpenGLRenderer::setupDrawMesh-   glVertexAttribPointer OpenGLRenderer: 1285
D/OpenGLRenderer(13909): GL Error after OpenGLRenderer::setupDrawMesh-   glVertexAttribPointer OpenGLRenderer: 1285
D/OpenGLRenderer(13909): GL Error after OpenGLRenderer::drawTextureMesh()-   glDrawArrays OpenGLRenderer: 1285
D/OpenGLRenderer(13909): GL Error after OpenGLRenderer::setupDrawMesh- glDisableVertexAttribArray OpenGLRenderer: 1285
```

Comment: You're running from the ui thread.  You must use threading. On phone otherwise I'd be more helpful.

Comment: I tried to do it on another thread but drawings are done by the UI thread, I dont know if there is another one to do that.

Comment: @user1977578 Sparksis is right. To draw in UI thread you can use `Handler`s, `AsyncTask`s or `Activity.runOnUiThread()` method.

Comment: I am already setting its layout params in Activity.runOnUiThread() method

Answer (score 1):

You can and should be using an AsyncTask for things you want done off the UI thread.  You will see many examples where the ProgressDialog is shown and hidden in various different lifecycle methods of the AsyncTask.

Here is one good example (there are many): [Android AsyncTask Progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar)

Comment: I am using progressbar not progress Dialog. How can I use it in my case? How can I make it drawn on another thread?

Answer (score -1):

You should use another thread for your calculations, you need to update your progress bar in your ui thread. You need a shared variable between your engine and your ui thread which would be refreshed by the engine thread and the ui thread should periodically check for changes.

Or, you can pass the progress bar's object to the engine thread which could call a method to update the state of your progress bar.