# how to a set progress bar till get a data from server using json?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android AsyncTask Progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar)

Am using login process,during tat time am getting the data from server is delay.so i want set a progress bar for tat delay.how to set progress bar till get a response from server.any know the answer please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.this); 
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Getting data from server
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent n = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
        startActivity(n);
    }
  }
```

**How to call this**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
LongOperation mytask = null;
mytask = new LongOperation();
mytask.execute();
```

Comment: how to pass a two string values in tat try catch blog.

Comment: after getting username and password from the edittexts then you can directly use them

Comment: thanks.then if no internet connection means progress bar to load not to dismiss.

Comment: do you want to show progressbar when there is no internet connection even??

Comment: ya i want even for no internet connecion.

Comment: no problem this code will work for your requirement

Comment: ya am use it for internet connection also thank u so much ram.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask in your code and put your code in doInBackground(....) process.

Show your progress dialog in onPreExecute and dismiss it in onPostExecute(...) .

Answer (score 0):

Add an infinite progressbar view to your layout and make it invisible first.

Create an `AyncTask` to do the server communication.

In `onPreExecute()` make the progressbar visible.

In `onPostExecute()` hide the progressbar again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onProcessupdate` method of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show("Downloading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (String myUrl : params) {

                try {

                    URL url = new URL(myUrl);
                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                    ucon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                    }
                    String str = new String(baf.toByteArray(), "UTF8");

                    return str;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    //error
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //error
                }
            }
            return "All Done!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    pd.setMessage("Downloading... (" + values[0] + "%)");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```