# How to use asynctask to display a progress bar that counts down?

Tags: android-asynctask, android, countdown

In my application i want the user to press a button and then wait 5 mins. i know this sounds terrible but just go with it. The time remaining in the 5 min wait period should be displayed in the progress bar.

I was using a CountDownTimer with a text view to countdown but my boss wants something that looks better. hence the reasoning for a progress bar.

Comment: You can set the progress to whatever you like with `setProgress()`. Just call it whenever you want to update it.

Comment: If its a set time make a fake progress bar.. Maybe a gif that last 5 minutes.

Comment: From the docs for `AsyncTask` ... **"AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)"** - you really shouldn't be running a 5 minute `AsyncTask`

Comment: Why don't you use a `CountDownTimer` with a `ProgressBar`?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: Here is more simple way check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar) out!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("waiting 5 minutes..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
    return null;
    }
}
```

Then write an async task to update progress..

```
private class DownloadZipFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Copy you logic to calculate progress and call
        publishProgress("" + progress);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
```

This should solve your purpose and it wont even block UI tread..

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your purpose. It will help others to identify right answer. thanks

Comment: change the second parameter of AsyncTask to Integer than you don't need to parse progress[0] to Integer.. and just write simply publishProgress(progress) without "" +

Comment: deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285047/showdialog-deprecated-whats-the-alternative

Comment: As its not overly obvious in this answer, the second paramter in `extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>` dictates what the expected parameters are for `onProgressUpdate` and `publishProgress`.

You also need to override the method