# Update fragment replaced by FragmentTransaction with Asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

Hi guys i'am here because I've already tried almost everything since running the fragment transaction in Asynctask or in a new thread nothing seems to work and i can't figure out by myself.

**What I've tried:**

[link](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

[link](http://android.okhelp.cz/asynctask-example-android-with-progressbar/)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069678/how-to-use-asynctask-to-display-a-progress-bar-that-counts-down)

and others

**My problem:**

- The fragment do some heavy work so i implemented the asynctask inside
  the
- fragment but i can't update the fragment
- My UI freezes when replacing with the fragment
- I create all my views programmatic
- My fragment returns a views
- I pretend to display a progressbar while the frag is not ready

**My main:**

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        FragTopics insideTopicsFrag = new FragTopics();
        insideTopicsFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment, insideTopicsFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**My fragment:**
**the createTopics returns a View with all the content, in another words it's the view that in the past was return in the onCreateView.**

```
public class FragTopics extends Fragment {
View v;
public FragTopics() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = new View(getActivity());
    new TopicsAsyncTask().execute();
    return v;
}
private class TopicsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    ManSession session;
    String courseId;
    Long topicId;
    String courseName;
    MoodleCourseContent[] courseTopics;
    MoodleCourseContent singleTopic;
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("loading...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ObtainData();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
        // The createTopics returns the View with all contents
        v = createTopics(singleTopic, courseName, courseId, topicId);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onCreateView` to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
v = new View(getActivity());
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           new TopicsAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    }, 200);    
return v;
}
```

Hope it still helps