# Loading spinner not showing correctly

Tags: spinner, android-spinner, android

I am trying to put a spinner while my data is loaded and UI updated so for this task I do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_road_details);     
    setTitle("Details");


    startButt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BeginJourney);    
    Map = (Button)findViewById(R.id.map_btn1);

    boolean GreenButtState = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("GreenButtState", false);
    boolean FastButtonState = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FastButtonState", false);


  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> LoadingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
  { 
      ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(RoadDetails.this);
      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
       {
          this.dialog.setMessage("Message");
          this.dialog.show();
       }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {    
            final HashMap<String, Object> trip1;

            Intent intent = getIntent();            
            mXmlRpcUrl = intent.getStringExtra("XmlRpcUrl");
            mSessionID = intent.getStringExtra("SessionID");
            mGetSavedTripFunc = intent.getStringExtra("GetSavedTripFunc");
            newTripID = intent.getIntExtra("newTripID", 0);
            variantID = intent.getIntExtra("VariantID", 0);
            Week = intent.getIntExtra("WeekState", 0);
            CityName = intent.getStringExtra("NameOfCity");
            Flag = intent.getIntExtra("Flag", 0);
            startLatitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("startLatitude", 0.0);
            startLongitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("startLongitude", 0.0);
            endLatitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("endLatitude", 0.0);
            endLongitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("endLongitude", 0.0);

            trip1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra("Variant");
            variant = new Variant();
            variant.Read(trip1);    

            startButt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RoadDetails.this, Localisation.class);
                    intent.putExtra("SessionID", mSessionID);
                    intent.putExtra("XmlRpcUrl", mXmlRpcUrl);
                    intent.putExtra("NewTripID", newTripID);
                    intent.putExtra("VariantID", variantID);
                    intent.putExtra("WeekState", Week);
                    intent.putExtra("NameOfCity", CityName);
                    intent.putExtra("Variant", (Serializable)trip1);
                    intent.putExtra("Flag", Flag);
                    intent.putExtra("startLatitude", startLatitude);
                    intent.putExtra("startLongitude", startLongitude);
                    intent.putExtra("endLatitude", endLatitude); 
                    intent.putExtra("endLongitude",endLongitude);                                   
                    startActivity(intent);          
                }
            });

            Map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    //Intent intent1 = new Intent (RoadDetails.this, MapDraw.class);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent (RoadDetails.this, OSMActivity.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("SessionID",mSessionID);
                    intent1.putExtra("endLatitude", endLatitude); 
                    intent1.putExtra("endLongitude",endLongitude);
                    intent1.putExtra("startLatitude", startLatitude);
                    intent1.putExtra("startLongitude", startLongitude);
                    intent1.putExtra("Variant", (Serializable)trip1);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            GettingData();
            this.dialog.dismiss();              
        }
    };       

    LoadingTask.execute((Void[])null);       
}
```

However when I do this there is a delay before opening the the activity that contains this code (I want the spinner to be there while the data is loaded) the spinner is not showing. There is just a delay (for the data to be loaded - lets also call it screen freeze for a 1 - 3 seconds) and thats it. What am I doing wrong? I want the spinner to show while the data is loaded and after that to be dismissed. I also what to mention that in the method GettingData(); I am changing the UI - adding Layouts dynamically, adding images etc.

Comment: There is no code of spinner in onCreate().

Comment: What do you mean? It is in the AsyncTask?!?

Comment: its not visible to us.. one more thing where you are dismissing the dialog even that is not in this given code.

Comment: In the onPostExecute.. yeah I did not copy the updated code

Comment: and even if I declare the spinner outside its not shown.

Comment: can you show us full code.?

Answer (score 0):

write ProgressDialog dialog; outside AsyncTask then

call

```
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(RoadDetails.this);

      dialog.setMessage("Message");
      dialog.show();
```

inside onPreExecute().

Hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

try this...this will work

```
  ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(RoadDetails.this);

   this.dialog.setMessage("Message");
   this.dialog.show();

//start your asynchronous task here

     load your data here

//end asynchronous task

 this.dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: What is the current status??

Comment: the spinner is not showing at all but all data is loaded correctly :/

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar