# Use progressBar instead of ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to use progress bar while downloading from server,Actually i was using progressDialog but it will be good look if i use progressBar instead of progressDialog.I have following code for Progress dialog .

```
 public class FeaturedData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    Home home;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    public FeaturedData(Home home) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.home = home;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //calling here method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(home, "", "", true);
    }
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4119009/940096) & [Also this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html)

Comment: Have you tried a google search for it? It is the very first result!

Comment: Actually i want to do it programatically don't want to declare in xml.

Comment: yeah @ anirudh4444 but that was not working...........So i have posted hare............

Answer (score 3):

As per your below comment:

> Actually i want to do it programatically don't want to declare in xml.

=> i would suggest you to take it inside the XMl layout.

- Inside the onPreExecute(), make it visible using `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`
- and inside the onPostExecute(), make it GONE by using `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: yeah @Paresh i can do this but i don't think its a good technique ,Is there any alternate solution...........then please suggest me........

Comment: If this is not a good technique....oh common i am using this since start. Still i would be happy to learn new technique if you found any :)