# Android: Progressbar stops on async task

Tags: android-layout, android-asynctask, android, android-progressbar

I am developing an application. In which my layout is as :

[image]

The code is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_1"
    android:layout_width="120sp"
    android:layout_height="120sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/appicon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_margin="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i am having the flow of java code as :

```
onCreate => Async task 1
doInBackground of Async task 1 => function 1 => from function 1 to function 2 => from function 2 to function 3 = > from function 3 return.

from onPost of Async task 1 => call Async task 2
doInBackground of Async task 2 => function a => from function a to function b => from function b to return.

from onPost of Async task 2 => call Async task 3
doInBackground of Async task 3 => function x => from function x to function y => from function y to return.
```

This is the fixed flow of my app.

**The issue is:** when my activity run the progressbar run fine but when async task execution starts the progress bar stops to move.

I tried the solution from the link as:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask)

But the out put is same.

Also i want to change the text of "run time changing text view" when it is on async 1 then again on async 2 and on async 3.

Please suggest me what to do with your valuable suggestions. Please reply for more clarification of question if needed.

Comment: Show progressbar code

Comment: @manojFedge just a question, why not execute all work (call all functions) using 1 asyncTask?

Comment: Any error you see in the cat log? if you had followed the link then it looks like there may be a lock for some object in your code flow.

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: @Yazan : As the task i am doing in function is reusable. So i can not write whole code in async. That is the need of app.

Comment: @ManojFegde i did not say to write the whole code in async, i asked why not CALL all the functions from 1 async task... anyways it's up to you...

Comment: Because i want to execute async 2 after completion of async 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, add

```
android:indeterminate="true"
```

for your ProgressBar. This enables the infinite animation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is partially resolved by your ans. But now to before finish the activity the progressbar stops for some time. And please let me know how to change text from async 2.

Comment: To change text you can use the onProgressUpdate method used inside of an AsyncTask. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Look at the onProgressUpdate method to update the UI thread from your AsyncTask