# ProgressBar into AsyncTask without xml

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

As the ProgressDialog is deprecated, I want to change this with a ProgressBar.
I wrote this code for a "MyAsyncTask", so this isn't connected to any xml file, but I can't see the ProgressBar.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressBar pb;

    public MyAsyncTask(AsyncResponse listener, Context context) {
        this.pb = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setMax(100);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        pb.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to create an XML file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119009/progressbar-togther-with-asynctask

Comment: It can't help me, because into this example, the ProgressBar is into an XML